# covering high dimensional hypercube by balls

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

suppose we are given the $d$-dimensional hypercube $H^d$ defined as

$$
    H^d:=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^d\epsilon_ie_i:\ \epsilon_i\in \{0,1\}\mbox{ for }i=1,\dots , d\right\}
$$
and $(e_i)_{i=1}^d$ the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

what is the asymptotics of the minimal number of (translates of) balls of radius $r>0$ convering $H^d$?

note that $H^d$ consists only of its vertices.

Comment: Do you want only the corners ($\epsilon_i\in\{0,1\}$) or the whole cube ($\epsilon_i\in[0,1]$)?

Comment: only the corners

Comment: You are asking about the smallest possible size of a (not necessarily linear) binary code of covering radius $1$. There are lots of results in this direction, just google to find them.

Comment: @seva thank you. yes, coding is the context for this question. i am looking for an elementary proof of a lower (asymptotic) bound. i would be very greatful if you could point me to a reference

Comment: You can find a comprehensive account, say, in "Covering Codes" by G. Cohen, I. Honkala, S. Litsyn, and A. Lobstein.

Comment: Are you letting the centers of the balls be points other than vertices? The corners of a square are contained in a unit ball around the center but not any vertex.

Comment: yes, the centers can be arbitrary.

Comment: @seva: thank a lot! just to save time: do you happen to know the asymptotic of the minimal covering number out of the back of your head?

Comment: I would be surprised if the case of arbitrary centers has been studied much.

Comment: The [covering code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) wikipedia page mentions a lower bound of $2^d/(d-1)$. Of course $2^d$ is an upper bound by putting a sphere on every corner.

Comment: A simple question: isn't $\ H^d=\{0\ 1\}^d\ $ ?

Comment: @usul: That lower bound (for $r=1$ before the OP changed the radius to be arbitrary) is not correct for the version where the centers can be arbitrary. If $d=3$ and $r=1$, all corners of the cube are contained in a unit sphere centered at the center of the cube.

Comment: @usul: For $r=1$ it only makes a difference in low dimensions.